# Boolean Search in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

In SharePoint 2010, there was Advanced Search web part in which you can use Boolean operations like And Or etc to get the relevant results. However in 2013, that web part was removed.

So would like to know the alternatives that are being used in 2013 that would ideally mimic the Advanced Search web part.

Please suggest or let me know if you need any further clarification on this.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 there's still an Advanced Search, but it's available as a stand-alone web part in a separate page in Search Center. First of all, as far as I know, it's only available in Search Centers. If you open the Search Center result page, the link to Advanced Search should be at the bottom of the page. You can also access the advanced search page directly by URL http://site/search/Pages/advanced.aspx.

I haven't tried this, but I believe this web part is designed to be placed in its own page and once you build your query, it will redirect you to the results page.